# node js & jade file upload error(500). log of file is proven as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to make an file uploading web page using nodejs, express and jade.

while focusing on the problem, It is file uploading at a webpage where multiple form is applied.

When I upload a file, the error message happens.

"Cannot read property 'uploadFile' of undefined"

the javascript funtion is

```
function uploadFile(req, res) {
    console.log("this is log1");
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.files.uploadFile.path);
    console.log("this is log2");
    fs.readFile(req.files.uploadFile.path, function (error, data) {
        var filePath = __dirname + "\\files\\" + req.files.uploadFile.name;
        fs.writeFile(filePath, data, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                res.redirect("back");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

the client code is

```
table(border="1")
- each stage in list.stage
  - var packFileNameArray= stage.packFileName.split("/")
  - var packVersionArray= stage.packVersion.split("/")
  - for (var i = 0; i < packFileNameArray.length; i++)
    tr
      td(width = '150')= stage.packName
      td(width = '150')= packFileNameArray[i]
      td(width = '50')= packVersionArray[i]
      td
        form(action='/upload', method='post',enctype='multipart/form-data')
          input(type='file', name='uploadFile')
          input(type='submit', name='Upload')
```

For this function, I add these into app.js file.

`var fs = require('fs');` --> this also typed into the js file where function is in.

`var serverManage = require('./routes/serverManage');` --> this is the js file where the funtion is in.

`app.post('/upload', serverManage.uploadFile);` --> this is triggered when the submit button is pressed

I serched two days for the answer. but I found none.

Please help me.

Thank you.

this is my whole app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var DBconnect = require('./user_modules/DBconnect');
var DBmodel = require('./user_modules/DBmodel');
var serverManage = require('./routes/serverManage');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.get('/manage', serverManage.getData);
app.post('/upload', serverManage.uploadFile);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

P.S 2. this is my whole serverManage.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose' );             
var DBmodel = require('../user_modules/DBmodel');
var fs = require('fs');

function getData(req, res) {
    DBmodel.findOne({'key': 'server'}).exec(function (err, data) {
            //console.log(data);
            res.render("manage", { title:"serverManage SAMPLE", list: data });
        });
}

function uploadFile(req, res) {
    console.log("this is log1");
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.files.uploadFile.path);
    console.log("this is log2");
    fs.readFile(req.files.uploadFile.path, function (error, data) {
        var filePath = __dirname + "\\files\\" + req.files.uploadFile.name;
        fs.writeFile(filePath, data, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                res.redirect("back");
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getData = getData;
module.exports.uploadFile = uploadFile;
```

Comment: how are you loading your `uploadFile` function? And can you please show your app.js code in a code-readable way?

Comment: I added whole app.js I hope to find and learn what I have missed and what should I know

Comment: a little more code than necessary in terms of the app.js, but not so much it's impossible to read through - the part relevant to this question is the `serverManage.upload`, is the function you've shown literally the only code bound to that, or does your `serverManage` contain more that's relevant? "Cannot read property 'uploadFile' of undefined" suggests you're not properly loading that `serverManage` dependency

Comment: Okay. I added whole serverManage.js file

Comment: this code looks fine, there's nothing to suggest an error "Cannot read property 'uploadFile' of undefined". Where does it say the error exists?

Comment: When I press 'submit' button.

Procedure is this.
1. press upload button. register an image file.
2. check filename is shown. press submit button.
3. the page is redirected to /upload and the error is shown.

Comment: no I mean where do you get the error: in node, in the browser, etc. It sounds like it's in the browser, in which case none of the node.js code you've shown is going to be relevant because that executes on your server, not in the browser (so can probably be removed from the post). What does the browser console say in terms of which file and line number the error occurs at? (and what JS is that trying to run?)

Comment: Dear Mike.

Thank you for your assistance. I tried using multer module
 and it worked. now I'm trying to find out writing error.

Thank you.